# Comment appele-t-on une source issue d'un livre ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Dans le but d'un projet, je dois lister mes sources.
Ainsi, les sources issues d'internet pourra avoir comme nom : **sources internet**.

Mais, comment appelle-t-on les sources issus d'un livre ?
J'ai fait une petite recherche sur internet mais je n'ai rien trouvé.
On pourrait quand même appeler ceci : *sources papier*.

Mais y a-t-il un nom particulier pour ce type de source ?

Comment: Non locuteur natif mais je crois qu'en même est faux. C'est quand même.

Comment: Bibliographie, références, liste des ouvrages utilisés, etc., ne conviennent-ils pas ?

Comment: "Références" et trop vague je trouve. Par exemple dans un dossier j'aurais une partie références mais après je veux créer des sous parties : Source internet ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon le lien ci-dessus :

https://www.reseau-canope.fr/savoirscdi/centre-de-ressources/fonds-documentaire-acquisition-traitement/le-traitement-documentaire/citer-ses-sources-et-presenter-une-bibliographie-lycee.html

l'on parle de

> Ouvrages
>
> Publication en série (périodique)

Pour ce dernier l'on fait la différence entre :

> Publication en série complète imprimée et
>
> Publication en série complète en ligne

Il y a aussi les

> Documents audiovisuels

et les

> Documents électroniques

les derniers comportant les sources tirées de la Toile.

Pour les ouvrages, articles dans des revues à comité de lecture, etc., je trouve que l'on peut utiliser sources imprimées (le cas échéant).

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble que l'on devrait les appeler tout simplement les sources bibliographiques en cela que le grecq « biblion » signifie « livre » et que le « livre électronique » n'est pas un livre, de plus que l'on ne devrait pas appeler un ensemble de sources comprenant des ebooks une bibliographie; cependant un terme tel que celui suggéré, c'est à dire « sources papier » ou « sources à support papier », en tant que terme général me parait être une excellente idée.

Comment: – oh-oh-oh, voilà une série d'affirmations plus contestables les unes que les autres : βύβλος signifie à l'origine papyrus, livre est un sens tardif (codex des Romains, auparavant on ne trouve que des volumina, des rouleaux) ; ce ne peut donc être le support qui fait le livre, livre électronique n'est pas un oxymore. En revanche bibliographie est plus pertinent, sauf que le sens est plutôt liste d'ouvrages, et qu'apparaissent en fin de livres des bibliographies avec des références imprimées ET des références Internet … Allons-y pour sources imprimées ? Mais s'il y a un manuscrit, on le brûle ?

Comment: @5915961T Je vais commencer par la fin et m'arrêter là, le reste de vos propos ne pouvant m'engager que de longs commentaires pour lesquels il n'y a pas de place et pour lesquels, de plus, il me manque trop d'expertise.

Comment: @5915961T  Avant d'incinérer quoi que ce soit, considérons que selon l'UNESCO cinquante pages sont tout d'abord nécessaires pour que l'appellation de livre soit acceptable (quelle sorte de page est une autre affaire) ; ce critère étant satisfait le manuscrit n'a rien de spécial en cela que c'est un « Assemblage de feuilles en nombre plus ou moins élevé, portant des signes destinés à être lus », la définition même du TLFi pour le mot « livre ».

Comment: – certes, mais le manuscrit par définition est écrit (à la main) et non imprimé (par machine), donc comment faire figurer un manuscrit dans une liste bibliographique si celle-ci est baptisée « sources imprimées ». Oui, c'est du mauvais esprit, mais constructif. « Les Misérables » en .PDF reste un livre, d'ailleurs vous le lisez dans une liseuse comme vous le lisez sur des pages imprimées au nombre supérieur à cinquante. Et la Bible a été transmise sur des rouleaux bien avant l'apparition du livre, pourtant son nom est synonyme de … livre.

Comment: @5915961T Strictement parlant, ce qu'en anglais on appelle un e-book, n'est pas une sorte de livre, ce n'est pas la sorte de livre qui est électronique, c'est quelque chose de nouveau; le livre a été défini en tant que papier, on veut continuer à  « penser papier » lorsqu'on dit livre et ne pas changer l'acception du mot ; le fait que le soit disant livre électronique  se lise comme un livre est encore discutable : on ne tourne rien du tout, on passe de page en page et puis on dira même d'écran en écran pour le format page entière et on ne parle certainement pas de feuilles.

Comment: Ce que l'on doit comprendre c'est qu'un nom manque pour le format divisionnaire du code et pour le nouveau support avec lequel on utilise ce format (puisqu'il ne peut pas être appelé « livre »). C'est la seule façon d'assurer que pour toutes les occurrences du mot « livre » qui restent à venir on identifiera sans hésitation ce qui est compris par « livre » ; c'est la seule façon de conserver à la langue une certaine pérennité. Que pourra-t-il bien se passer lorsque l'utilisation du livre papier est désuète ? Continuera-t-on à écrire « e-book » ? Probablement pas… on ne dira plus que « book ».